# Wrong result with a namespace in a XSL transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, xslt-1.0, xml-namespaces

I have a problem with a xsl transformation. I dont get the result that I expect and I cant see what's wrong. I think that the problem is something related with the namespace. Can you help me?

This is the xml that my service will receive. I want to separate the multivalued elements to some new nodes.

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap-env:Header/>
   <soap-env:Body>
      <testService facade="Test" xmlns="http://new.webservice.namespace">
         <input>
            <Data1>Data 1</Data1>
            <Data2>Data 2</Data2>
            <ParamResponses>
               <ParamResponse>
                  <Name>DATAONE</Name>
                  <ValParam>Text 1</ValParam>
               </ParamResponse>
               <ParamResponse>
                  <Name>DATATWO</Name>
                  <ValParam>Text 2</ValParam>
               </ParamResponse>
               <ParamResponse>
                  <Name>MULTIVALUED</Name>
                  <ValParam>001</ValParam>
                  <ValParam>002</ValParam>
               </ParamResponse>
               <ParamResponse>
                  <Name>DATATHREE</Name>
                  <ValParam>Text 3</ValParam>
               </ParamResponse>
            </ParamResponses>
         </input>
      </testService>
   </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

This is the xslt I'm applying

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@facade">
        <xsl:attribute name="facade">
               <xsl:text>FacadeReplaced</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="input/ParamResponses">
      <ParamResponses>
         <xsl:for-each select="ParamResponse[Name!='MULTIVALUED']">
            <ParamResponse>
               <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
            </ParamResponse>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </ParamResponses>
      <MultiValueParamResponses>
         <MultiValueParamResponse>
            <Name>MULTIVALUED</Name>
           <xsl:variable name="items" select="//input/ParamResponses/ParamResponse[Name='MULTIVALUED']/ValParam"/>
            <ValueList>
               <xsl:for-each select="$items">
                  <value>
                     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                  </value>
               </xsl:for-each>
            </ValueList>
         </MultiValueParamResponse>
      </MultiValueParamResponses>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is what I obtain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap-env:Header/>
    <soap-env:Body>
        <testService facade="FacadeReplaced" xmlns="http://new.webservice.namespace">
            <input>
                <Data1>Data 1</Data1>
                <Data2>Data 2</Data2>
                <ParamResponses>
                    <ParamResponse>
                        <Name>DATAONE</Name>
                        <ValParam>Text 1</ValParam>
                    </ParamResponse>
                    <ParamResponse>
                        <Name>DATATWO</Name>
                        <ValParam>Text 2</ValParam>
                    </ParamResponse>
                    <ParamResponse>
                        <Name>MULTIVALUED</Name>
                        <ValParam>001</ValParam>
                        <ValParam>002</ValParam>
                    </ParamResponse>
                    <ParamResponse>
                        <Name>DATATHREE</Name>
                        <ValParam>Text 3</ValParam>
                    </ParamResponse>
                </ParamResponses>
            </input>
        </testService>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

But this is what I want to obtain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap-env:Header/>
    <soap-env:Body>
        <testService facade="FacadeReplaced" xmlns="http://new.webservice.namespace">
            <input>
                <Data1>Data 1</Data1>
                <Data2>Data 2</Data2>
                <ParamResponses>
                    <ParamResponse>
                        <ParamResponse>
                            <Name>DATAONE</Name>
                            <ValParam>Text 1</ValParam>
                        </ParamResponse>
                    </ParamResponse>
                    <ParamResponse>
                        <ParamResponse>
                            <Name>DATATWO</Name>
                            <ValParam>Text 2</ValParam>
                        </ParamResponse>
                    </ParamResponse>
                    <ParamResponse>
                        <ParamResponse>
                            <Name>DATATHREE</Name>
                            <ValParam>Text 3</ValParam>
                        </ParamResponse>
                    </ParamResponse>
                </ParamResponses>
                <MultiValueParamResponses>
                    <MultiValueParamResponse>
                        <Name>MULTIVALUED</Name>
                        <ValueList>
                            <value>001</value>
                            <value>002</value>
                        </ValueList>
                    </MultiValueParamResponse>
                </MultiValueParamResponses>
            </input>
        </testService>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

If I add a xmlns to the element input, I've obtained it correctly but that isn't what I'll receive by webservice.

The transformation shoulb be XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is indeed related to namespaces. In the original XML, you have this line

```
 <testService facade="Test" xmlns="http://new.webservice.namespace">
```

THis means the **testService** element, and all elements below it will be part of the "http://new.webservice.namespace" (unless overridden by other namespace declarations).

However, in your XSLT, there is no mention of this namespace. This means when you have an expression like this...

```
<xsl:template match="input/ParamResponses">
```

It is looking for elements that belong to NO namespace. As your source XML has elements within a namespace, this template will not match anything. In your case, the identity template will match instead, leading to your output being the same as the input.

So, what you need to do is declare the namespace in the XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:ns="http://new.webservice.namespace">
```

Then, whenever your reference an element from the input XML, you must use the relevant namespace prefix

```
<xsl:template match="ns:input/ns:ParamResponses">
```

Note the namespace prefix "ns" can actually be anything really. It is the URI "http://new.webservice.namespace" that has to match the URI in the XML.

Additionally, for any new elements you output, if you want these to be part of the namespace, you can either prefix them with the namespace prefix, or you can declare a default namespace in your XSLT, which will apply to any new element you output that does not have a prefix

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:ns="http://new.webservice.namespace"
     xmlns="http://new.webservice.namespace">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@facade">
        <xsl:attribute name="facade">
               <xsl:text>FacadeReplaced</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="ns:input/ns:ParamResponses">
      <ParamResponses>
         <xsl:for-each select="ns:ParamResponse[ns:Name!='MULTIVALUED']">
            <ParamResponse>
               <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
            </ParamResponse>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </ParamResponses>
      <MultiValueParamResponses>
         <MultiValueParamResponse>
            <Name>MULTIVALUED</Name>
           <xsl:variable name="items" select="//ns:input/ns:ParamResponses/ns:ParamResponse[ns:Name='MULTIVALUED']/ns:ValParam"/>
            <ValueList>
               <xsl:for-each select="$items">
                  <value>
                     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                  </value>
               </xsl:for-each>
            </ValueList>
         </MultiValueParamResponse>
      </MultiValueParamResponses>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! I can't give you any reputation, but I really appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

This XSLT stylesheet:

```
<!-- Define a 'web' namespace that is equal to the default namespace in your input.
     This way, we can match elements in your input (like ParamResponse, Name) 
     that belong to this namespace. 
     We also need to define the same namespace as the default, so that we can
     exclude it from elements we output. -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:web="http://new.webservice.namespace"
                xmlns="http://new.webservice.namespace"
                exclude-result-prefixes="web #default">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- The identity transform: outputs identical XML to the input, in the
       absence of template overrides. -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@facade">
    <xsl:attribute name="facade">
      <xsl:text>FacadeReplaced</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Match ParamResponse elements in the web namespace. -->
  <xsl:template match="web:ParamResponses">
    <!-- Output the single-valued ParamResponse elements first. These will
         match the identity transform and just get copied out. -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="web:ParamResponse[not(web:Name='MULTIVALUED')]"/>
    <!-- Output a new MultiValueParamResponses element and apply-templates to
         all ParamResponse elements with a MULTIVALUED Name element. -->
    <MultiValueParamResponses>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="web:ParamResponse[web:Name='MULTIVALUED']"/>
    </MultiValueParamResponses>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- For the MULTIVALUED ParamResponse elements, change the element name
       and start a new ValueList element. -->
  <xsl:template match="web:ParamResponse[web:Name='MULTIVALUED']">
    <MultiValueParamResponse>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="web:Name" />
      <ValueList>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="web:ValParam" mode="multi"/>
      </ValueList>
    </MultiValueParamResponse>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Change the name of the ValParam elements for MULTIVALUED
       ParamResponse elements. -->
  <xsl:template match="web:ValParam" mode="multi">
    <value>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </value>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces the following output XML when applied to your input:

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soap-env:Header />
  <soap-env:Body>
    <testService facade="FacadeReplaced" xmlns="http://new.webservice.namespace">
      <input>
        <Data1>Data 1</Data1>
        <Data2>Data 2</Data2>
        <ParamResponse>
          <Name>DATAONE</Name>
          <ValParam>Text 1</ValParam>
        </ParamResponse>
        <ParamResponse>
          <Name>DATATWO</Name>
          <ValParam>Text 2</ValParam>
        </ParamResponse>
        <ParamResponse>
          <Name>DATATHREE</Name>
          <ValParam>Text 3</ValParam>
        </ParamResponse>
        <MultiValueParamResponses>
          <MultiValueParamResponse>
            <Name>MULTIVALUED</Name>
            <ValueList>
              <value>001</value>
              <value>002</value>
            </ValueList>
          </MultiValueParamResponse>
        </MultiValueParamResponses>
      </input>
    </testService>
  </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```